# Javascript trying to iterate over getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I want to start by saying I am fairly new to Plain JavaScript so I am sorry if it is something obvious.

I am trying to remove errors when someone resubmits the form with the following code.

```
let div = document.getElementsByClassName('error')
if (div.length > 0 ){
    console.log(div);
    console.log('Length: ' + div.length);
    for (i = 0; i <= div.length; i++){
        console.log('i= ' + i)
        let e = div[i]
        e.innerHTML = ''
        e.classList.remove('error')
    }
}
```

That works, sorta, I end up getting every other div with the error class being altered instead of all of them.

[Developer Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjMJ4.png)

Comment: `i < div.length` , and the if is unneccessary.

Comment: I couldn't understand your issue of getting every other div, the code seems fine, but when you call `for (i = 0`, you should scope the `i` (`for (let i = 0`) and you should stop before the `div.length` (`i < div.length`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.getElementsByClassName()` function returns a **live** NodeList. That means that when you change the class on an entry, it disappears from the list. The length of the list drops by one, so your iteration skips every other entry.

One good way to do it is to just operate on the first thing in the list until the list is empty:

```
while (div.length) {
    let e = div[0]
    e.innerHTML = ''
    e.classList.remove('error')
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that, thank you I will give it a try.

Comment: Another option is to create an array from the nodeList. `div = Array.from(div);`

Comment: You could also use querySelectorAll which returns a static rappresentation

Comment: Yup there are several different ways of dealing with the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

## Live and "Static" HTMLCollections / NodeLists

The older methods `.children`, `.getElementsByTagName()`, `.getElementsByName()`, `.getElementsByClassName()`, etc. return a Live Collection of DOM Objects. This means if any object (i.e. elements, i.e. `<div>`, `<span>`, etc,) in this collection (a.k.a. **HTMLCollection**, a.k.a. **NodeList**) is modified, or removed, or if a new object is added, the overall collection will change immediately. So on every loop you actually have a different array (or array-like object), therefore the results are a product of an ever changing group of values and quantities.

- Use `.querySelectorAll()` which returns a "static" NodeList.
- With a `for` loop, declare your increment var (`i`) by:

  declaring it outside of the `for` loop as: `var i = 0;`

  OR

  declaring within the `for` loop as: `let i = 0;`

## Demo

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll('.error');
var qty = div.length;
for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
  console.log('i= ' + i);
  var d = div[i];
  d.innerHTML = 'GOOD';
  d.classList.toggle('error', 'good');
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  color: blue;
  font: 400 15px/1.3 'Consolas';
}
```

```html
<div class='error'>ERROR</div>
<div class='error'>ERROR</div>
<div class='error'>ERROR</div>
<div class='error'>ERROR</div>
<div class='error'>ERROR</div>
<div class='good'>GOOD</div>
<div class='error'>ERROR</div>
<div class='error'>ERROR</div>
<div class='error'>ERROR</div>
<div class='error'>ERROR</div>
```